# Outlook has already begun transmitting this message. at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_UserProperties()

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook

I am parsing outlook folders and accessing user properties that i have defined but some times it gives this error-
Outlook has already begun transmitting this message.
   at `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem.get_UserProperties()`.
Really want some experts suggestions.